# Can we use the recursive least squares as a learning algorithm to an ADALINE?

Tags: learning-algorithms, linear-regression

I'm new to neural network, I study electrical engineering, and I just started working with [ADALINEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADALINE#Learning_algorithm).

I use Matlab, and in their [Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/adaptive-neural-network-filters.html) they cite :

> However, here the **LMS (least mean squares) learning rule**, which is
>   much more powerful than the perceptron learning rule, is used. The
>   LMS, or Widrow-Hoff, learning rule minimizes the mean square error and
>   thus moves the decision boundaries as far as it can from the training
>   patterns.

The LMS algorithm is the default learning rule to linear neural network in Matlab, but a few days later I came across another algorithm which is : [Recursive Least Squares (RLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) in a 2017 Research Article by **Sachin Devassy** and  **Bhim Singh** in the journal: **IET Renewable Power Generation**, under the title : [Performance analysis of proportional resonant and ADALINE-based solar photovoltaic-integrated unified active power filter](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8049622/) where they state :

> ADALINE-based approach is an efficient method for extracting
>   fundamental component of load active current as no additional
>   transformation and inverse transformations are required. The various
>   adaptation algorithms include **least mean square**, **recursive least**
>   **squares** etc.

**My questions are:**

- Is RLS just like LMS (i mean can it be used as a learning algorithm too)?
- If yes, how can I customize my ADALINE to use RLS instead of LMS as a learning algorithm (preferably in Matlab, if not in Python) because I want to do a comparative study between the two Algorithm!

Comment: Really you want use an Adlines NN instead of perceptrons ? Sorry for the a few off-topic comment, but surprises me.

Comment: LMS and RLS are not learning rules, but cost functions. RLS th same than LMS after apply a filter to the error measures, usually a forget factor.

Comment: Please feel free to comment, i'm new so honestly i don't know, if there is something you want to suggest i'm listening, thank you

Comment: If there are not a non-linear element we are more in the area of linear filtering than in the one of AI. Moreover, as combination of linear elements can be flatten, multi-layer concept disappears. Non-linear activation functions as Heaviside (perceptron), sigmoid, ... are the center of the NN.

Answer (score 1):

RLS is a second order optimizer, so, unlike LMS which takes into account an approximation of the derivative of the gradient, RLS also considers the second order derivative. You can study more about second order methods in sub-section "8.6 Approximate Second-Order Methods" of the following book available online:

https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html

Deep Learning
An MIT Press book
Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville